# Can't find my winforms control in WPF toolbox

Tags: c#, wpf, winforms, user-controls

I made custom winforms control from one project, then I switched to WPF. I referenced the old project, but my custom controls doesn't show up in toolbox, and there seems no "easy" way to add them to my winforms host. Do I have to add them in code?

Also, if i decide just to re-write the codes in wpf, how difficult/different would it be?

Comment: I have edited your title. Please see, "[Should questions include “tags” in their titles?](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/19190/)", where the consensus is "no, they should not".

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Because WPF works so much differently than WinForms, there is no interactive designer for WinForms in WPF. Use a [`WindowsFormsHost`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms751761.aspx) to place the WinForms control in your WPF window.

You can do this through XAML as:

```
<Window x:Class="Window1"
xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml/presentation"
xmlns:x="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml"
xmlns:wf="clr-namespace:My.Custom.Assembly;assembly=My.Custom.Assembly"  
Title="HostingWfInWpf">
<Grid>
    <WindowsFormsHost>
       <wf:MyCustomControl />
    </WindowsFormsHost>
</Grid>
</Window>
```

Replace `My.Custom.Assembly` with your own assembly and `MyCustomControl` with your control name.

If possible, rewriting your control for WPF would be the best option, as it will allow for WPF features such as hardware acceleration.

Comment: In general, how difficult would it be for something to be rewritten? I have a control with a lot of drawing in it. What about performance?

Comment: WPF is supposed to me much faster because of hardware acceleration, and just being more "modern", but I've actually found drawing to be a bit slower, at least in my application. (Although it heavily relys on databinding and XAML drawing through `ItemSource`s) I'd imagine code based drawing would be extremely fast. (Instructions are sent straight to the GPU in WPF). There is nothing in WinForms you can't do in WPF really, it is just a matter of learning the different API.

Comment: Thanks. I'll do that I guess. It's time... I have been using winforms since a child, lol